# Mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_assoc are null

Tags: php, mysqli

For a school project, I am creating an imaginary online banking site that acessess a database at school for imaginary account information. Every time I view account I get two mysqli errors. one on line 26 in person.class.php and another on line 52 on veiwaccounts.php I traced the main cause of that error in my person class but can't seem to fix it in any way. The errors are

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in .../person.class.php on line 26
>   Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in .../viewaccounts.php on line 52

Here is a sample of some code from the viewaccounts.php file:

```
if($currentMember)
{
    $currentMember = new Person($memberid);
    $accounts =  $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts();

    //HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS $accounts = $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts(); 

    //Loop through accounts
    while($account = mysqli_fetch_assoc($accounts)) {
        //Retrieve balance
        $bankaccount = new Bankaccount($account['BankAccountID']);
        $bankaccount->connection = $conn;
        $balance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bankaccount->retrieve_current_balance());
```

Here is the code for the person class file:

```
public function retrieve_all_accounts() {
    $accounts_query = "SELECT BankAccountID FROM BankAccount WHERE UserID = " .$this->memberid;
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $accounts_query);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I added more info on the errors at the top.

Comment: how are you initializing connection in this class? maybe you need a global var to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    //Accounts
    $currentMember->connection = $conn;

    //instantiating class here since suggested code from video fails to do it.


if($currentMember)
{
    $currentMember = new Person($memberid);
    $accounts =  $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts();

}else
{
    echo "<p>not working</p>";
}
```

To

```
if(!$currentMember) {
  $currentMember = new Person($memberid);
}
$currentMember->connection = $conn;
$accounts =  $currentMember->retrieve_all_accounts();
```

I would also shift this into the first PHP code block for readability.

You are instantiating a new `Person` only if `$currentMember` evaluates to `TRUE` - if the `unserialize()` call fails `$currentMember` will evaluate to `FALSE`, and that is when you should create a new object.

Also you assigned the `connection` property first, which will be destroyed when you create the new `Person`, which you are presumably doing every time otherwise you would see more warnings.

You should also refactor the entire logic that tests whether the `Person` was saved in the `$_SESSION` - for a start, sessions will serialize objects themselves so you should not need to call `serialize()`/`unserialize()`. What you should do instead is define an [`__autoload()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function and just store the object instance in `$_SESSION`.

I also note that your development server seems to have [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) on - turn it off, it is bad practice to use it as it is disabled pretty much everywhere in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

you are instantiating your `person` class with a member id from `$memberid` variable. try passing a value of your `$memberid` here[where you are passing a value to instantiate the object of the class `person`] and use `var_dump` to debug whether its really returning any value.
and place `$currentMember->connection = $conn;` after instantiating the object. Most probably your problem is causing here. You were trying to access the public variable connection of the class `person` before instantiating it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with your `Database` object initializing the connection. It's likely not connecting because the error indicates that you are not providing a `mysqli` object to `mysli_query()`.

Try looking into [mysqli_connect_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) and [mysqli_connect_errno()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php) in your `Database` class to figure out if there was an error while connecting and work from there.